# Paypal Subscription Button IPN

Tags: paypal

If I create a PayPal subscription button and set `notify_url` to my backend, I get the initial signup response, so that's great. What I am wondering is if Paypal will continue to send responses here based on that button for all future payments/cancels, or if it will only send IPNs to the global IPN handler as defined in my profile.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you can define a IPN url in your account settings for all payments. But you can define an individual notification url for each payment via the notify_url field in the button.

Then, that url is used only for this transaction.